# ?: (urls.E006) The STATIC_URL setting must end with a slash

Tags: python, django, database

I was trying to migrate my new schema for my database in django when I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I looked online and I saw that if you wrap your paths with str(), the error goes away.
But then I got this error:

```
?: (urls.E006) The STATIC_URL setting must end with a slash.
```

I tried doing the obvious thing and changing `STATIC_URL = BASE_DIR.parent / "svelte" / "public"`(what I think was causing the error) That didn't work, so I tried `STATIC_URL = BASE_DIR.parent / "svelte" / "public" /`. That also didn't work, so know I need help.

Comment: `STATIC_URL` is the prefix for the generated URLs for your static files, usually just "/static/". Do you mean to be setting `STATIC_ROOT` to this value instead? Can you post the rest of your settings for static files

Comment: STATIC_URL = BASE_DIR.parent / "svelte" / "public"

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'site_media' / 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR.parent / "svelte" / "public" / "build"
]

Comment: maybe you have `STATIC_URL = ...` also in other place and it has path without `/`. First you could use some tool to search `STATIC_URL` in all files - ie. `grep` on Linux